# Why output of even integers is not working properly

Tags: c

Sample Input:

4

Output:

0 2 4 6

Why this isn't working properly?

```
int main()
{
    int i, n, sum = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if ( i % 2 == 0)
            sum += i;
        printf("%d ", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you're printing the sum of even integers from 1 to n, not outputing even numbers

Comment: and why don't just use `for (i = 2; i <= n; i += 2)` and get rid of the even test?

Answer (score 0):

```
        int i,j, count = 0, n, sum = 0;
        scanf("%d", &n);           

        for (j = 0;; j++) {
            if (j % 2 == 0) {
                printf("%d", j);
                count++;
                if (count == n) {
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: If I put " printf("%d ", sum); " in if statement then the output is coming : 2 6 

But output should come for sample input 4 = 0 2 4 6

Comment: Then, how I can get this output for this sample input: 4, output: 0 2 4 6

Comment: why are you doing sum if you only wants to display even numbers ?

Comment: I need to get output for 4 = 0 2 4 6
That is why, I'm keeping the summition for i in sum.

Comment: @Arnob - ok nderstood

Answer (score 0):

The answer you get on executing the quoted code will not be 0,2,4,6 because you have added the value of i to the previous value of sum at each instance when the value of i is a multiple of 2.
 so as per the flow of you code

- when i=1 you have 0 printed as this would print the Value of sum without adding i
- when i=2 you have 2 printed as this would print the Value of sum after adding i which is 2
- when i=3 you have 2 printed as this would print the current value of sum without adding i which is 2
- when i=4 you have 6 printed as this would print the current value of sum after adding i which is 2 so 2+4=6

to get the output desired by you you should add 2 to previous value of sum rather than adding i.
ie

```
int main()
{
    int i, n, sum = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if ( i % 2 == 0){
           printf("%d ", sum);
           sum += 2;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to print out the even values up to a user supplied value. Do that like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            printf("%d ", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```